# Encrypting a ZipPackage Stream in Memory

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, stream, zip

I am using .NET 4.0 and trying to do the following:

1. Create a System.IO.Packaging.Package in Memory
2. Add Items to the package
3. encrypt package before it is written to file.

I tried to create a MemoryStream and add the files to it by:

```
 using (var memoryZip = Package.Open(_memoryStream, FileMode.Open))
 {
      var partUri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(_fileUri);
      var part = memoryZip.CreatePart(
          partUri,
          String.Empty,
          CompressionOption.NotCompressed);

      using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
           fileStream.CopyTo(packagePart.GetStream());
      }
  }
```

Then I tried to encrypt it and saved it to a file:

```
 _key = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
 {
      Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_password);
      IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_password);
 }
 var fileStream = File.Open(_fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
 var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(streamToFile, _key.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

 //Convert filestream to byte[]
 var streamAsBytes = new byte[(_memoryStream.Length)];
 _memoryStream.Read(streamAsBytes, 0, streamAsBytes.Length);

 //Encrypt
 cryptoStream.Write(streamAsBytes, 0, streamAsBytes.Length);

 fileStream.Close();
 cryptoStream.Flush();
 cryptoStream.Close();
```

However, when I go to decrypt it:

```
 var fileStream = new FileStream(_zipFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
 var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, _key.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

 using(var zipPackage = Package.Open(cryptoStream, FileMode.Open))
```

I get a FileFormatException: "File contains corrupted data."

This isn't the same message you would get if decryption failed.  I would expect that the stream that went in during encryption is the same one as the one that came out so any idea why the package would be corrupted?

Comment: Don't close the file stream *before* you flush the crypto stream, you'll miss the last chunk. Favor the *using* statement.